# Кодировка массива object в base64

Tags: c#

Есть консольная программа, код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] mas = new int[4] { 128, 15, 25, 175 };

            byte[] binData = new byte[2 + 2 + 4 + 4];

            BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[0]).CopyTo(binData, 0);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)mas[1]).CopyTo(binData, 2);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[2]).CopyTo(binData, 4);
            BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mas[3]).CopyTo(binData, 8);

            string BASE64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binData);

            Console.WriteLine(BASE64);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Хочу сделать такую же кодировку только из массива object. Вот пример:

```
object[] mas = new object[4] { 128, 15.1, "abc", 'a' };
```

Но при выполнении этого кода вылетает вот такая вот ошибка на первом же приведении типов.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Заданное приведение является
>   недопустимым.'

Что можно с этим сделать? Возможно нужен лист а не массив object?

Comment: Почитайте вот эту [статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). Она даст понимание про boxing и unboxing типов.

Comment: @Kazantsev я знаю что такое запаковка и распаковка. Я спросил можно ли реализовать мою задачу через массив object или лучше сделать лист.